# How to send pdf file thorugh email id using html,javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-mobile

In my HTML form the user request to loanform.pdf link...while clicking the link it ask user email id after that pdf form send through user mail id.........how ll solve this can anyone gives some suggestion or example?

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

Download the PHPMailer script from here: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer